# Run arbitrary zsh command for all subfolders

Tags: zsh

I'm currently using this function to run a command for all subfolders in zsh.

```
forsubdirs() {
   for dir in *; do
     (cd ${dir} && echo $fg_bold[yellow]${PWD##*/}$reset_color && $@ && echo '\n')
   done
}
```

I use it like this: `forsubdirs git pull`
The problem, though: it does not work with aliases. How to execute an arbitrary ZSH command (including aliases and lists of commands separated with "&" or ";") for all subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to pass complex commands as argument you need to quote syntactic elements like `;` and `&`. The arguments then need to be explicitly evaluated with the `eval` command. For example:

```
forsubdirs () {
    for dir in *(/) ; do
        ( cd $dir && echo $fg_bold[yellow]${PWD##*/}$reset_color && eval $@ && echo '\n' )
    done
}

forsubdir 'ls -1 | sed "s/^/    /"'
```

Also, I would suggest using `*(/)` instead of plain `*`. It matches only directories, so that the function does not even try to run `cd` on regular files.

Comment: Thanks, I think there's a small typo though: shouldn't "%fg_bold" be "$fg_bold"?

Comment: @lonelyass Yes, that's right. I have fixed it now. Thanks.